# DirectX11 Sampling 1D Texture Gives Incorrect Color

Tags: directx-11, sharpdx

For background I am using SharpDX version 4.2.0
I am having a hard time getting the correct color in a pixel shader by sampling a 1D texture.

Here's how I am making the 1D texture, knowing that textures can be finicky if they are not multiples of DataBox.RowPitch:

```
public static ShaderResourceView CreateUpdateable1DTexture(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, int width)
    {
      width = ((width / 128) * 128) + 128;
      // Describe and create a Texture2D.
      Texture1DDescription textureDesc = new Texture1DDescription()
      {
        MipLevels = 1,
        Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
        Width = width,
        ArraySize = 1,
        BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write,
      };

      var tex1D = new Texture1D(device, textureDesc);
      var resourceView = new ShaderResourceView(device, tex1D);
      tex1D.Dispose();

      return resourceView;
    }
```

Here's how I am updating the texture:

```
public static unsafe void Update1DTexture(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, ShaderResourceView textureResource, SharpDX.Color[] colors)
    {
      var modifiedColorLength = ((colors.Length / 128) * 128) + 128;
      // double check the bounds are fine for this texture
      var texture = textureResource.ResourceAs<Texture1D>();
      if (texture.Description.Width != modifiedColorLength)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't update this texture with this color array, texture size mismatch");

      byte[] textureStreamBytes = new byte[modifiedColorLength * 4];

      fixed (SharpDX.Color* colorPtr = &colors[0])
      {
        fixed (byte* bytePtr = &textureStreamBytes[0])
        {
          System.Buffer.MemoryCopy(colorPtr, bytePtr, textureStreamBytes.Length, colors.Length * 4);
        }
      }

      DataBox databox = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(texture, 0, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None, out DataStream stream);
      if (!databox.IsEmpty)
        stream.Write(textureStreamBytes, 0, textureStreamBytes.Length);
      device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(textureResource.Resource, 0);
      texture.Dispose();
    }
```

The color array only has 1 color in it, it should be R:0.75, G:0.5, B:0, A:1
I verified in Visual Studio Graphics Debugger that my texture is reaching the pixel shader with that color as the first color

[image: 1d texture]

The problem is in my shader the reported color is R:0.874509800, G:0.749019600, B:0, A:0

Here's my sampler state description:

```
SamplerStateDescription samplerDesc = new SamplerStateDescription()
        {
          Filter = Filter.MinMagMipLinear,
          AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Border,
          AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Border,
          AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Border,
          MipLodBias = 0,
          MaximumAnisotropy = 1,
          ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Always,
          BorderColor = new Color4(255, 255, 0, 0),
          MinimumLod = 0,
          MaximumLod = float.MaxValue
        };
```

and all I am doing to sample this texture is this:

```
Texture2DArray shaderTextures : register(t0);
Texture1D upperLeftCoordsTexture : register(t1);
SamplerState SampleType;

float4 upperLeftCoords = upperLeftCoordsTexture.Sample(SampleType, 0);
```

again, upperLeftCoords reports R:0.874509800, G:0.749019600, B:0, A:0

but I am expecting R:0.75, G:0.5, B:0, A:1

Also I am sure I am passing the textures in the right order:

```
deviceContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureArray);
deviceContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(1, upperLeftCords);
```

So don't know what I am doing wrong and getting the wrong color in the pixel shader, do you happen to know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I suspect it's blending with the border color. DirectX uses 'middle of the upper-left pixel' is actually not 0,0. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-resources-coordinates).

Comment: I changed the samplerstate's texture address mode to clamp, and still getting the same problem, I think that rules out bordercolor because bordercolor is only used if the texture address mode is border right?  I would have thought that texture addressing a texture would just give you the raw value at the texture address if you're not using an srgb pixel format.

Comment: Try point sampling...

Comment: If Chuck's suggestion doesn't work try using an operator[] like this: float4 upperLeftCoords = upperLeftCoordsTexture[0]. All values except alpha channel look like they are interpolated between your value and border color, maybe you can try to change your border color and see if you are getting other values.

Comment: Not solving your problem, but you can call stream.Write(colors) directly with datastream, no need to convert to byte array.